# Pulling branch gets unable to connect error

Tags: git, github

I was hoping somebody might be able to give me a hand by pointing out where I'm going wrong with github.  I have my branch cloned down to my machine and I'm attempting to fetch from another user's branch on github.

```
>git remote add rally25rs git://github.com/rally25rs/SubSonic-3.0.git
>git fetch rally25rs master

github.com[0: 207.97.227.239]: errorno=No error
fatal: unable to connect a socket (No error)
```

As far as I can tell this is the correct procedure.

Comment: do you have ssh keys in place on github?

Comment: For what it's worth, I was just able to clone the repo using that URL.

Comment: Eimantas, I do indeed.  I've messed that up before, but I get a different error message.

Comment: Your commands (`git remote add … && git fetch …`) worked for me in an empty, freshly inited repo (`mkdir foo && cd foo && git init`).

What is your OS, OS version, and Git version? The error implies that connect(2) is returning < 0, but not setting errno to a useful value.

Comment: Windows 7 and git 1.6.5.1.1367.gcd48

Comment: Is that msysgit or Git under Cygwin? If it is msysgit, make sure you are using the latest release (it looks like you might be; I have no Windows, so I can't really tell what the "1.6.5.1" release has in it). Either way, you might try the other one. If you are using msysgit, you could try the mailing list http://groups.google.com/group/msysgit, or the issue tracker http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/list.

Comment: I have Win7 with that version of git from msysgit and it works, I have seen weird socket errors when there are firewall problems and the port gets blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax

```
 git remote add rally25rs git://github.com:rally25rs/SubSonic-3.0.git
```

is what you want.  Note the : after github.com